# PHP - Times Value by Percentage - VAT

Tags: php, variables

I have a price $special which lets say is 10. I want to add the UK VAT rate of 20% of this value to display the VAT inclusive price. I have tried the below.

```
        $vatrate = 0.20;

        $endPrice = ((int)$vatRate/100)*$special)+$special;

        echo $endPrice;
```

But i am seeing an error., Well the page is blank so this means an error of some sort ?

Comment: Take a look at your parentheses.

Comment: Your formulae is also wrong.  Either set $vatrate to 20 or remove the division by 100.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this..

You have already created percent of vat
by 0.20    so no need to divide by 100 here again.

```
> $vatrate = 0.20;
>     $endPrice = ($vatRate*$special)+$special;
>     echo $endPrice;
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no `int` function in PHP (and if there was it would not be contained in ()) and @K.K.Agarwal is right, you have already converted to percent so dividing by 100 is unnecessary.

Try:

```
$vatrate = 0.20;
$endPrice = ($vatRate*$special)+$special;

echo $endPrice; 

//should be 0 since $special is not defined
```

Example: http://codepad.org/vUGiriV0

Comment: if i echo $special i receive a result ? how can define $special

Comment: You must have set $special earlier in your code.  In the example you provided it is not there so php treats it as 0.